# IF statement with or conditions (HTML and Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, or-condition

Why does this not function correctly?

No matter what value you enter it ALWAYS returns "Invalid Ticket Type"

```js
function start() {
  var TickType;
  TickType = document.getElementById("TicketType").value;
  TickType = String(TickType);
  var TicketQty = document.getElementById("TicketQty").value;

  if (TickType != "A" || TickType != "B" || TickType != "C") {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Invalid Ticket Type";
  }

  if (isNaN(TicketQty)) {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Non numeric qty has been entered";
  }

  if (TicketQty < 1 || TicketQty > 100) {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Qty is outside valid range";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Ticket Sales</h1>
<p>Enter the ticket type (A, B or C)</p>
<input type="text" id="TicketType">

<p>Enter the quantity required (1-100)</p>
<input type="text" id="TicketQty">

<p>
  </br>
</p>

<button onclick="start()">Click me</button>
<p id="msg"></p>
```

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: use `TickType.toString()` instead of `String(TickType)`

Comment: Please see the snippet I made for you. I clicked the `<>` and created a [mcve]

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen or nothing since it is already a string, especially if OP adds `value=""` to each field as recommended. - A .trim() is a better idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&&` instead of `||`

```
if (TickType != "A" || TickType != "B" || TickType !=  "C"){
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Invalid Ticket Type";
}
```

**Explanation**

When `TickType = "A"`, `TickType != "B"` and `TickType !=  "C"` conditions are true.

Here two of the condition is always `true`, so it goes into the `if` statement

NOTE: Add a trim and a parseInt to the vars and `value=""` to the fields and emptied the message before testing

```js
function start() {
  var TickType = document.getElementById("TicketType").value.trim();
  var TicketQty = parseInt(document.getElementById("TicketQty").value, 10);
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "";

  if (TickType != "A" && TickType != "B" && TickType != "C") {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Invalid Ticket Type";
  }

  if (isNaN(TicketQty)) {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Non numeric qty has been entered";
  }

  if (TicketQty < 1 || TicketQty > 100) {
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Qty is outside valid range";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Ticket Sales</h1>
<p>Enter the ticket type (A, B or C)</p>
<input type="text" id="TicketType" value="" />

<p>Enter the quantity required (1-100)</p>
<input type="text" id="TicketQty" value="" />

<p><br/></p>

<button onclick="start()">Click me</button>
<p id="msg"></p>
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh I see now how silly me error was, thank you for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets try to figure out **why** its not working correctly

You expect `TickType` to be either `A` or `B` or `C`. Now when you evaluate following condition, lets say `TickType="A"`

```
if (TickType != "A" || TickType != "B" || TickType !=  "C"){
```

- `TickType != "A"` would yield `false` as it is equal.
- But then `TickType != "B"` would yield `true` as `TickType` is `A` and not `B`

and `if` finds matched condition and sets innerHTML as `"Invalid Ticket Type"`

---

Now the correct condition would be if its not in either value i.e.

```
if (TickType != "A" && TickType != "B" && TickType !=  "C"){
```

Now this will work but what if you have say 10 such characters in future, adding 10 such `&&` condition would make code less readable.

---

**Alternatives**

1. Create an array with all such possibilities and check for index.

```js
var possibilities = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

function isAvailable(c){
  return possibilities.indexOf(c) > -1
}

console.log(isAvailable("G"))
console.log(isAvailable("A"))
```

2. Create a regex and test for validity:

```js
var possibilities = /(A|B|C|D|E)/

function isAvailable(c){
  return possibilities.test(c)
}

console.log(isAvailable("G"))
console.log(isAvailable("A"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here ...

```
if (TickType != "A" || TickType != "B" || TickType !=  "C"){
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Invalid Ticket Type";
}
```

This condition always evaluates to true, even if you enter any of the A,B,C. For instance, you enter an A, the first inequality fails, which is ok, but all the other will succeed and you'll get the "Invalid Ticket".

The logic says that:

```
!(A || B || C) <-> !A && !B && !C
```

so change that if-condition to:

```
if (TickType != "A" && TickType != "B" && TickType !=  "C"){
   document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Invalid Ticket Type";
}
```

This will do the trick ...
If any of the TickType's is A or B or C, the ands will fail and you won't get an "Invalid Ticket"

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
if (TickType != "A" && TickType != "B" && TickType !=  "C")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AND` instead of `OR` in condition. Where, you're checking if TicketType isn't one out of A,B & C. So condition will be

```
if (TickType != "A" && TickType != "B" && TickType !=  "C")
{
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Invalid Ticket Type";
}
```